# Re-load AdSense banner on router change?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to re-load the AdSense banner ads on router change. Obviously, the problems comes from the fact, that I'm trying to re-add the script and the html, but I don't know how I'm supposed to do it...

---

*This is a test of one of the answer's suggestions.*

**Edit:**

```
<div v-if="ads" class="ads"><ins v-if="adsense" :key="id" class="adsbygoogle" style="display: inline-block; width: 320px; height: 50px;" data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXX" data-ad-slot="XXX"></ins></div>
...
data () {
  return {
    device: {},
    ads: false,
    adsense: false,
    id: 1
  }
}
...
methods: {
  AdSense: function () {
    (window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({})
  }
}
...
mounted: async function () {
  let adsense = document.createElement('script')

  adsense.setAttribute('data-ad-client', 'ca-pub-XXX')
  adsense.setAttribute('async', '')
  adsense.setAttribute('src', 'https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js')

  document.head.appendChild(adsense)

  this.ads = true

  this.adsense = true

  this.AdSense()
}
...
watch: {
  $route (to, from) {
    if (to !== from && to.name !== 'authorize' && this.device.platform === 'web') {
      this.id++
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every time you call the `AdSense` method it tries to append another `script` tag to the head of the document. And like the error suggests, you should only have the google ads script only once.

So, first step would be to split this script tag creation part to a separate method and make sure it is only called once.

Secondly, for re-rendering the ad element, you could try giving it a `key` attribute. And when you want the ads to be reloaded, increment the key to a new value.

```html
<ins v-if="adsense" class="adsbygoogle" :key="id"></ins>
```

```js
data() {
    return {
        id: 1;
    }
},
watch: {
    $route (to, from) {
        if(to !== from) { 
            this.id++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I ended up using https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/2694377 and setting it to refresh every 30 seconds. I've accepted the answer, since that's the best way to re-render a component. The problem with AdSense was that after I include the JS it was adding additional `<ins>` tags and it became too complicated. Thanks for your time!